# Advantages of using Spring's KafkaListener over Apache's KafkaConsumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I understand that KafkaConsumer is a client from Apache's Kafka library, which is pollable on demand, and is therefore in an infinite loop that sends out a heartbeat based on an interval. KafkaListener is an annotation applied to a method so that Spring Kafka will invoke it to process a message.

That said, I'm not sure what the design advantages / disadvantages are of either approach. Does one allow for a better or worse consumption pattern, in your opinion? And if so, what is the difference?

Comment: Spring's wraps the other and "does more". But, there is marginal overhead using _any_ higher-level library. If you're not using Spring, obviously you wouldn't use it, and you could basically be asking the same question about Quarkus's SmallRye consumer or VertX's implementation...

Comment: So what does that imply if it's wrapping the KafkaConsumer? Easier to work and write around? Any design considerations there? And what do you mean by "does more"?

Comment: Yes, it is wrapping and providing other properties that allow for redirection to Spring lifecycle handlers and bean-injection

Answer (score 2):

See the goals on the [project page](https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#overview); essentially it provides a higher level abstraction, taking care of the low level stuff so you can concentrate on the business logic. It uses familiar concepts for Spring users that use other technologies (JMS, RabbitMQ etc).

It generally provides a faster on-ramp for those new to Apache Kafka.